# Is it possible to both insert and update in a single sqlite statement?

Tags: python, sqlite, sql-update, sql-insert

I want to insert a row from a table into a new table but change one value as I do so. Is it possible to do this in one statement?

Currently I have:

```
db = sqlite3.connect('C:/Desktop')
db.execute("""insert into table2 select * from table1 where
    ID = {0}""".format(5))
db.execute("""update table2 set column = {0} where ID = {1}""".format("new string",5)
db.commit()
db.close()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `*` with the actual column list, and then replace that column with the new value:

```sql
INSERT INTO Table2
SELECT ThisColumn, ThatColumn, 'new string', OtherColumns
FROM Table1
WHERE ID = ?;
```

Answer (score 0):

yes,you can use

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO table(column_list)
VALUES(value_list);
```